# Spawning a customized sprite with text

Tags: unity, c#, spawning, unity-ui

I'm making a game where I have circles filed with words or pictures drop from the top of the screen to the bottom. they should spawn right above and then drop.
I just started using unity a couple days ago and I managed to do this with a simple sprite, but I couldn't fill it with the info I wanted and from searching online it seems like it can't be done.

So I decided to try with buttons instead, since those can be given text and images(I think) but i'm not sure how to do so.

with the circles I passed an object of them to the script and then used
`newCircle = Instantiate(Circle, temp, Quaternion.identity);`
but with buttons everything seems to work weird because there's also the need for the canvas and the units are different so I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple script to put on your sprite prefab that looks a bit like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMP;

public class WordSprite : MonoBehavíour {
    public Sprite sprite;
    public TextMeshPro word;

    public void Setup(string text) {
        word.text = text;
    }
}
```

Now you can add the text as a child object, and assign a reference to both the sprite and the text in the inspector.

Now your spawner can expose an inspector field:

```
public WordSprite prefab;
```

Then you can instantiate and populate it just like you did with the regular sprite before:

```
var wordSprite = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
wordSprite.Setup(putYourChosenWordHere);
```

> from searching online it seems like it can't be done.

Don't give up so easily, especially on something this simple.

Comment: thx for the answer, tbh i didnt quite understand where everything goes and when i tried to add a reference to a TextMeshPro it wouldnt let me.
any way i found a good guide on youtube so it worked out

Comment: When you have questions about how to do something, you should ask them.

Comment: lol ofc, but i wanted to try and manage with the info you gave me + more searching :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a great guide on YouTube, I'm not sure if it's ok to post a link here so please tell me if its not.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJ5tyiW_L24.

The idea is we make a Canvas with a Text into a child of the object and we simply resize both the canvas and the text to fit the sprite object.
we need to change the canvas into world space and also change the pixels per unit since it's going to be much much smaller (changing to 100 worked well for me).
with the Text make sure to mark the "Best Fit" box otherwise the letters will likely be too big for your sprite.

Comment: Links itself are ok as reference but better is if you describe as good as possible what/ how you solved it. It is always possible that a link target gets taken down or a future answer seeker has to watch a 2h explanation of how to do something.